# Vue Multi-select not showing all the options

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I'm using https://vue-multiselect.js.org in my Vue component. I am using AJAX to update the select list option, and I see in the inspector that there are 10 values.

[image]

But when I actually click into the multiselect list, I only see a subset of these items and I can't figure out why.... Here are my multi-select props/events:

```
<multiselect
        v-model="organization"
        :allow-empty="true"
        :loading="loading"
        :options="organizationSearch"
        :preserve-search="true"
        @search-change="searchOrganizations"
        @select="organizationSelected"
        @remove="organizationDeselected"
        placeholder="Search Organizations"
        label="name"
        track-by="id"
        class="multiselect my-3"
>

</multiselect>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out. I dug into the component code a bit and found that all the options WERE in the `options` prop, but there were only 3 in the `filteredOptions` computed field. I added
`:internal-search="false"` into my component and then this fixed it.

I think the ultimate issue here had to do with conflict between the internal filtering, and the dynamic update of the options I was doing via AJAX.

Below is the definition of filteredOptions in the actual component definition.

[image]

Comment: THIS WORKED PERFECTLY! I had the same problem when dealing with an array of objects and this solved it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It could be more helpful if you expand the `options` array in the inspector, so we could see what properties are presented in the objects.

> `track-by` is used to identify the option within the options list thus it’s value has to be unique.

You set `track-by="id"` and `label="name"`, so your `options` array should look something like this:

```
options: [
  { id: 1, name: 'Option #1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Option #2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Option #3' },
],
```

Make sure that all the items in your `options` array have an `id` property and it is unique for all of them, because the items with the same `id` will not appear in the multiselect list.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the structure of your `options`.

It shows that they are objects when they should probably be literal values.